# How could the web server (PHP) be the first how connect to the Android application

Tags: php, android, web-services

How could the web server(pHP) be the first how connect to the android application?
Is there method that allows the server (PHP) to be the first to connect to the Android application?

Comment: Webservers usually do not connect. Please explain better what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As @greenapps mentioned in the above comment, web-servers usually do not connect directly to your android application.

In this case you need to design an interface between your android application and web server, basically you can send your data to your web server via `POST/GET` methods and get the result with `JSON` encoding, for more information I suggest you to take a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) article.

There is also a useful example here:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Servers cannot connect to client like mobile for multiple reasons:

1. The servers do not know the client IP - it's allocated dynamically
2. The clients do not have any server running to which the PHP-server can connect
3. For the server to connect to the client, it must be able to create a socket to the other-server.

Well, in a nutshell, that's not how you work with mobile + server.

What exactly are you looking for any how?

Comment: Je pense que vous êtes ne sait pas mon problème